# Unistalling ReSharper 4.5 took away right-click code editor context menu for VS 2008!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper-4.5

**Environment Context**

- Windows 7 (*hosted in Virtual Box 3.0.4*)
- Visual Studio 2008
- Resharper 4.5

**Issue**

After uninstalling Resharper 4.5 from VS2008 the "normal" code editor context-menu (mouse right click) doesn't work, the way to let it work just one time is to let it appear by click the keyboard key (near the altgr key) and the clicking again the mouse right button.

Any suggestion to restore the "normal" VS2008 behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running devenv.exe with the /ResetSetting.